# iOS Downloadable In-App Purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm developing an iOS app that needs downloadable in-app purchases.

My app manipulates photos and has "templates" over the user's photos. These templates show some realtime data that comes from  JSON api. A template consists of 3 files: `.m`, `.h`, and `.xib`. Can these files be included in an in-app purchase? Or would Apple reject or limit this type of IAP?

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you're just restricting access to those options unless the user purchases the IAP, then Apple **will** accept it

Comment: It sounds like the code for the templates needs to be compiled.  You will need to include the compiled templates in your app and just enable them when the user completes the in-app purchase.  You can't download and compile code on demand.

Comment: Hi guys, Thank you all for the answers, in your opinion what should be the ideal way to do dynamic skins (get data from json, with custom designs) that users can download